# Initially hidden items "breaks" on Listview('refresh')

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I can see that this issue was a [bug in v1.3](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5680), but has been fixed. But I'm having this issue now with JQM 1.4.

In my HTML I have the following code:

```
<ul class="storeList"
    data-role="listview"
    data-inset="true"
    data-filter="true"
    data-enhanced="true"
    data-input="#store-filter"></ul>
```

The `data-enhanced="true"` instructs the filterable widget to skip these DOM manipulations during instantiation

Then in jQuery I get data with Ajax (on page load) and dynamically add list items:

```
// loop
// If user is in city A, hideItem = True
if(hideItem) {
    $(li).attr('class', 'ui-screen-hidden');
}
storeList.append(li);
// loop-end

// listview needs to be initialized before it can be enhanced/refreshed.  
// That's why we do a .listview() first then .listview('refresh')
$('.storeList').listview().listview('refresh');
```

The problem is that the `.listview('refresh')` removes the `ui-screen-hidden` class.

There is something about this on the [Filterable Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/) (See `Providing pre-rendered markup` section), but I get non the wiser.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you add the listitems, are they initially hidden because they would not meet the currently entered filter criteria? or are you trying to do a reveal/autocomplete kind of thing?

Comment: Yeah. I know what city the user is in, so I hide the other list items on page load. I've hacked this now and add my own hidden element and it works. I think I actually have to do this anyway because if I only use `ui-screen-hidden`, autocompelte will remove this class once I start using autocomplete.

Comment: By the way, I just found this: http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/ and it says `Widgets that don't have option enhanced (yet) are: Listview, Selectmenu, Panel, Toolbar, Navbar, and Slider.` I don't know how old this document is and if this has been implemented.

Comment: Could you just write the city into the filter box and then call .filterable( "refresh" ); so that the filterable widget hides the listitems?

Comment: See my answer below @ezanker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to show a dynamically created list of stores, but only show the stores for the city where the user is currently located in.

[image]

To do this I wanted to filter the list by using the `enhanced` option in the [Filterable Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/).

```
<ul data-enhanced="true"></ul>
```

The `data-enhanced="true"` instructs the filterable widget to skip the DOM manipulations during instantiation and thus speed up the initiation / loading process.

I then added `ui-screen-hidden` to all list items that was not Oslo. Since the list is created dynamically I have to refresh the Listview.

`$('.storeList').listview().listview('refresh');`

The problem is that the Listview refresh removes `ui-screen-hidden` class and my entire list is shown.

As it turns out, it seems that [Listview has not yet gotte](http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/)n the `enhanced` feature.

> Widgets that don't have option enhanced (yet) are: Listview,
>   Selectmenu, Panel, Toolbar, Navbar, and Slider.

@ezanker suggested that I could put my location in my input filter. That will not work because of two reasons:
1. The filter on the view page is filtering by store name, not location.
2. Even if it was filtering by location, it would reveal all stores a soon as I removed the city name.

So what I did was to add my own `hidden` class to the list items.

```
if(location !== (store.city+store.countryID)) {
    $(li).attr('class', 'hidden');
}
```

To change location, I go to a new page, select location and return to my view page. To apply my new location, I do some coding in `pagebeforeshow` event.

```
$('#storeListPage').on('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
    //First we remove all hidden items
    $('.storeList li').removeClass('hidden ui-screen-hidden');

    // Then we only shows the items for selected city
    var location = $('a.selectLocation .city').text() + $('a.selectLocation .countryID').text();
    var selector = '.storeList li:not([data-location="'+location+'"])';
    $(selector).addClass('hidden');
});
```

Now my list is filtered by location and I can further filter the list by store name.

There are probably other ways to achieve this, but this works for me :)